# angularjs client and spring backend user login and session management

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, authorization, session-cookies

I have a mobile website written in angularjs, with my backend in Spring Boot. Right now, I have my own login page and can login a user without any trouble. However, if the user ever clicks "back", "refresh", etc., the client loses the user's id and login info (obtained from server on login). I need to make sure that this info is maintained and clicking "back" or "refresh" doesn't break everything.

Secondly, a user that knows the url's after login can type those url's in the browser and access them without logging in. I can stop them accessing anything on the server, but not sure what I can do on the client to redirect them to a login page in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that everything running in browser is `stateless`, there's no way to keep trace of the previous state.

Right now, if the user performs a refresh (or another similar action), Angular loses everything (AuthData included).

You have many way to work around that limit:

1. Perform an http request after the application bootstrap (have a look at the `angular.module().run` method
2. Save a cookie and use the server to print initial data layer directly on the dom via json
3. Save on local/session storage

Personally, I prefer cookies because that lets the server to work decoupled from the client.

Comment: For cookies, would there be any issues regarding whether the browser allows cookies? And if yes, how could I overcome them?

Comment: If the browser (which means the user) doesn't allow cookies, you can't use cookie... simply show the login form always.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your comment...*"if the user ever clicks "back", "refresh", etc., the client loses the user's id and login info (obtained from server on login)."*

Is there any reason you need to maintain the user id or login info after a successful authentication?

If Spring Security is setup for basic authentication, after a successful login, a Session Cookie will be sent back on the response to the client. On all subsequent requests to the server, the same Session Cookie will be sent on the request and the previously authenticated session will be re-established. You just need to ensure that your Angular client is passing cookies when issuing requests.

Take a look at this [sample](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) on how this is done.

Comment: Yes, I need to maintain their userID as it is an identifier used for subsequent requests to the server (this is a chat app).